# Closing a RabbitMQ connection shared across threads in a .net console

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I have a .net console that delivers a high volume of messages to RabbitMQ that shares a Connection object across all threads. What are the suggested practices for closing the connection at the end of execution? We notice the console will not exit until the connection is explicitly closed. Setting AutoClose = true after channel creation tears down at inconsistent points so perhaps we are missing an additional setting.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?